# Black screen when showing Admob ads

Tags: android, cordova, admob, cordova-plugins, cordova-admob

The screen is just black when showInterstitial ad is called using the cordova-plugin-admobpro plugin>>

Calling this to preload the ad:

```
if (AdMob) AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
    publisherId:'pub-xxxx',
    adId: ca-app-xxxx,
    autoShow: false, isTesting: false 
});
```

Then I'm calling this later to show the ad

```
AdMob.isInterstitialReady(function (ready) {
     if (ready) {
         AdMob.showInterstitial();
         }
});
```

When I log onAdLoaded, onAdShow and onAdFailLoad, everything seems to be loading, showing and not failing, but the screen is just black. I have tried different adIDs and have tried adding other ad networks to no avail

[image]

Comment: I'm using this plugin https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova which works fine. Have you tried changing `isTesting` config option? Normally both plugins should have it